# PHP Code is not displaying all results from databse in site but displays them in database

Tags: php, mysql, select, webstore

Have a little problem printing all the appropriate categories into a select input. Right now, it should add all categories which have children. The problem is, it's not entirely right. It only shows the very first from the main category and the subcategories that belong to it, but it is not displaying the next main category item.

For example:

1. Main category: Snares
   Sub Category : Tama
   Sub Categorys Sub Category: Starphonic
2. Main Category: Cymbals
   Sub category: Paiste

It only displays the first main category (for eg. Snares) and everything linked to it.

I also want it to display those categories which have no sub categories AND those that have.

```
  $result = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(nimi) AS kpl FROM samppa_kategoriat");
  $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
  $kpl = $row['kpl'];
  mysql_free_result($result);
  $sql = "SELECT
   samppa_kategoriat.nimi AS KatNimi,
   samppa_kategoriat.layer AS layerA,
   samppa_kategoriat.children AS lapsetA,
   samppa_alikategoriat.nimi AS AliNimi,
   samppa_alikategoriat.layer AS layerB,
   samppa_alikategoriat.parent AS parentA, 
   samppa_alikategoriat.children AS lapsetB,
   samppa_alikategoriatB.nimi AS AliNimiB, 
   samppa_alikategoriatB.parent AS parentB,
   samppa_alikategoriatB.layer AS layerC 
   FROM 
   samppa_kategoriat, 
   samppa_alikategoriat,
   samppa_alikategoriatB
  WHERE
   (samppa_kategoriat.nimi = samppa_alikategoriat.parent
  AND samppa_alikategoriat.nimi = samppa_alikategoriatB.parent)";
  $res = mysql_query($sql);
  $i = 0;
  while($n = mysql_fetch_object($res)){
  $countA[$i]   = mysql_real_escape_string(strip_tags($n->lapsetA));
  $countB[$i]   = mysql_real_escape_string(strip_tags($n->lapsetB));
  $nimiA[$i]    = mysql_real_escape_string(strip_tags($n->KatNimi));
  $nimiB[$i]    = mysql_real_escape_string(strip_tags($n->AliNimi));
  $nimiC[$i]    = mysql_real_escape_string(strip_tags($n->AliNimiB));
  $parentA[$i]  = mysql_real_escape_string(strip_tags($n->parentA));
  $parentB[$i]  = mysql_real_escape_string(strip_tags($n->parentB));
  $layerA[$i]   = mysql_real_escape_string(strip_tags($n->layerA));
  $layerB[$i]   = mysql_real_escape_string(strip_tags($n->layerB));
  $layerC[$i]   = mysql_real_escape_string(strip_tags($n->layerC));
  $i++;
  }
  for($i=1;$i<$kpl;$i++){
    echo "<option>$nimiA[$i] = $countA[$i] </option>";

    for($i=0;$i<$countA[$i];$i++){
      echo "<option>- $nimiB[$i] = $countB[$i]</option>";
    }
      for($i=0;$i<$countB[$i];$i++){
      echo "<option>-- $nimiC[$i]</option>";
      }
     }



        mysql_free_result($res);
        mysql_close($conn);
```

?>

Comment: Just a side note - you should be escaping data (with `mysqli_real_escape_string` - not `mysql_*` functions as they have been deprecated) when you put it **IN** your database. When you take it out, you should be using something like `htmlentities` to encode it for HTML purposes.

Answer (score 1):

Youre using the same variable name in your for loops.

```
for($i=1;$i<$kpl;$i++){
  echo "<option>$nimiA[$i] = $countA[$i] </option>";

  for($i=0;$i<$countA[$i];$i++){
    echo "<option>- $nimiB[$i] = $countB[$i]</option>";
  }

  for($i=0;$i<$countB[$i];$i++){
    echo "<option>-- $nimiC[$i]</option>";
  }
}
```

When they're all using variable $i, the outer loop will not maintain its correct value.
Try to change your outer loop to `$j` instead of `$i`.

Comment: It did change, it dispalys the first  category right and all the sub categories belonging to it, but when it displays the second main category item, it displays the first categories sub categories instead of the second main categories sub categories

Comment: Yes, because you're calling everything $i. Also your index here must be changed to $j. $countA[$i]

Comment: Alright, I changed all the $i to something else in every For loop. Right now, we are close to getting it solved. RIght now, it posts the same main category and its subcategories TWICE. So , I tried assigning the array number manually in echo "<option>$nimiA[$i]...." and guess what? It seems that array number 0 and 1 are both the same main category, 2 and 3 are are the second main category. Why does it not add it to the second array number which in this case would be 1? As that right now seems to be the problem why it wont display the other main category at all, instead the same one twice.